# Exporting an inkscape drawing to latex

Tags: errors, inkscape

I need help please, I'm new to using latex and inkscape. I saved my image from inkscape as a pdf_latex file, in the same directory as my latex document. Then in my latex document I added the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\def\svgwidth{columnwidth}
\input{imagename.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

I also included graphicx.

When I run pdflatex it says process excited with errors. I clicked on it to see the errors, but it says no latex errors detected. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How does the resulting pdf look (after running `pdflatex`), is the output what you expect or not? Which editor/compiler/operating system do you use? Could you try to discover the actual error message, maybe there is some information in the log file?

Comment: can you try `\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}` ?

Comment: There's no pdf output, it says file not found.  I'm using windows 8, texmaker.

Comment: Am I supposed to run something else before running pdflatex

Comment: Please post a full MWE (minimum (non)working example). Let's see a whole complete small document with some text as well as your figure, that compiles when you comment out the figure.

Comment: Why don't you export your image in `.pdf` format and use `\includegraphics`?

Comment: Sam sorry there was a typo, I do have it as {\columnwidth}

Comment: It works with \includegraphics , but I was worried about the resolution of the picture in latex

Comment: I doubt that **pdf_tex** is a standard file extension. Are you sure about the extension?

Comment: [This](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) is probably the documentation you need. It is included in TeX Live so `texdoc svg-inkscape` should also work if you have TL installed. There are also example files showing how the results of the export can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for .pdf_tex file.
Inside it, it has some infos and point to pdf file generated.

`\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{file.pdf}}%`

Make sure that file is pointed right.
If generated file has multiple pages, change all of them.

When in subfolders like

`img/`

You should consider adding it manually or using the

`\graphicspath{{img/}}`

I also prefer using:

`\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{1\columnwidth}{!}{file.pdf_tex}}
\end{figure}`

Comment: Somehow I'm still getting an error,  think I'll just leave the file as a pdf and not a pdf_tex file. Thank you though

Comment: @user101097 I am not really surprised. I have no idea how this is supposed to work. Which isn't to say that it doesn't. But it certainly isn't at all clear from this. In any case, don't use `h` as the sole placement option for floats. If you don't want the image to move, don't make it float at all.